# django-autocomplete-light: Select2 static files not checked out

Tags: python, django, jquery-select2, django-autocomplete-light

I'm trying the Django-autocomplete-light package following [this tutorial](https://django-autocomplete-light.readthedocs.io/en/master/tutorial.html) and I'm stuck in this error:

> ?: (dal_select2.E001) Select2 static files not checked out
>
> HINT: Run git submodule update --init in DAL

I installed it downloading the .zip and using pip, then added to my INSTALLED_APPS just before django.contrib.admin, implemented a class-based view just like the tutorial and registered it in urls.py. The reverse test in the tutorial works, but when I run server I get the error. What have I missed?

**Here's full traceback:**

> Unhandled exception in thread started by .wrapper at 0x00000000042B0598>
>
> Traceback (most recent call last):
>
> File "C:\Users\\lib\site-packages\django\utils\autoreload.py", line 226, in wrapper fn(*args, **kwargs)
>
> File "C:\Users\\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\commands\runserver.py", line 116, in inner_run
>
> self.check(display_num_errors=True)
>
> File "C:\Users\\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 472, in check
>
> raise SystemCheckError(msg)
>
> django.core.management.base.SystemCheckError: SystemCheckError: System check identified some issues:
>
> ```
> ERRORS:
>  ?: (dal_select2.E001) Select2 static files not checked out
>  HINT: Run git submodule update --init in DAL
> ```

I don't get the hint. I think I've missed something installing, but if you need my code just tell me. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution for this. Please note that pip install of zip/archive of the repo will not include submodules automatically. Thus you need to install the package using following command. This will install the latest master version of the package.

```
pip install -e git+https://github.com/yourlabs/django-autocomplete-light.git#egg=django-autocomplete-light
```

or

```
pip install git+https://github.com/yourlabs/django-autocomplete-light.git
```

Recently this has been addressed in the [documentation](http://django-autocomplete-light.readthedocs.io/en/master/install.html) as well. Checkout the "Note" there.

Comment: Nope, I wasn't. Sorry.